# Comma separated list SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 3 columns: "Dept Number" and "Class Number" and "Description". If the user enter values 21-1 and 24-12 where the left term represents the department number and right term represents the class number, I want to search the table for those items based on its dept number and class number (Here, dept# = 21 and class# = 1) and displays its description. How can I write the SQL query for that?

**Note:** the user can enter more than 1 value. So, I am thinking about making 2 lists: 1 for dept# and other for class#. But, I am not sure how to search the database using these lists

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Oracle? I doubt you are using both.

Comment: First you need to decide which DBMS you are using. sql server <> oracle. Then you need to explain your question more clearly. In general you are going to have a tough time when you allow delimited lists as search criteria. You will have to split that into rows first so you can use it as search criteria.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a code example for SQL Server and Oracle.

SQL Server:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE dept = CAST(SUBSTRING(N'21-1',1,CHARINDEX(N'-',N'21-1')-1) as int)
    AND class = CAST(SUBSTRING(N'21-1',CHARINDEX(N'-',N'21-1')+1, LEN(N'21-1')) as int)
```

Oracle

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE dept = CAST(SUBSTR(N'21-1',1,CHARINDEX(N'-',N'21-1')-1) as int)
    AND class = CAST(SUBSTR(N'21-1',CHARINDEX(N'-',N'21-1')+1, LENGTH(N'21-1')) as int)
```

Please tag your question correctly. I hope this helps you.